# android PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse compilation error

Tags: android, google-api

I am trying to follow below tutorial to get place information

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

Facing compilation issues for getCount() method and below error

`for-each loop` not applicable to type com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse

```
PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();

int count =0;
count++;
if (likelyPlaces.getCount() < M_MAX_ENTRIES) {
   count = likelyPlaces.getCount();
} else {
   count = M_MAX_ENTRIES;
}
for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces)
{}
```

Using android SDK 27, can anyone help me in fixing this ?